# How to prove equality of sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove that $[x \in \mathbb{Z}:6|x] = [x \in \mathbb{Z}:2|x]\cap[x\in\mathbb{Z}:3|x]. $

I understand that I have to prove this from multiple angles, but this is my first time working with proofs using sets. How do I go about tackling a problem like this?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally speaking, for two sets $X$ and $Y$, we prove that $X\subset Y$ by showing that $x\in X$ implies $x\in Y$. $X$ and $Y$ are equal iff $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that each set is a subset of the other. I.e., take an $x \in \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 2 \mid x \} \cap \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 3 \mid x \}$.
Then, because 2 and 3 are coprime, we have $6 \mid x$, so $x \in \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 6 \mid x \}$. This means $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 2 \mid x \} \cap \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 3 \mid x \} \subset \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 6 \mid x \}$. The reverse is similar.

Comment: How would I formally write the reverse? Appreciate the tip!

Comment: @Mitchell, follow the same steps I did, but reverse the sets: take an $x \in \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 6 \mid x \}$, then show that 2 and 3 both divide $x$, and that will imply that $x \in \{ \dots \} \cup \{ \dots \}$.

Answer (score 1):

- **Proof requirement.** To show that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal, we can show that the two
  sets are subsets of each other, i.e. $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq
     A$. Specifically, we can show if $y \in A$, then $y \in B$, and
  conversely if $y \in B$, then $y \in A$. We can think of this as
  loosely analogous to showing ''both sides'' of if and only if
  statements $(\iff)$.
- **Proof trick.** Since the sets we have here have nice algebraic representations, we will show that if a number $y$ can be
  represented as a multiple of $6$, it can also be represented both as
  a multiple of $3$ and as a multiple of $2$, and vice versa.
- Suppose $y \in \{x \in \mathbb Z : x|6\}$. Then $6$ divides $y$,
  meaning that there exists a $z \in \mathbb Z$ such that $y$ can be
  written as $y = 6z$. But then $y = 3\cdot(2z)$ and $y = 2 \cdot (3z)$, and certainly $2z$ and $3z$ are integers as well. Therefore $3$ divides $y$ and $2$ divides $y$, so $y \in \{x \in \mathbb Z : x |3\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb Z : x|2\}$.
- Suppose $y \in \{x \in \mathbb Z : x |3\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb Z : x|2\}$. Then there exists a $z \in \mathbb Z$ such that $y = 3z$ and another $z^\prime \in \mathbb Z$ such that $y = 2z^\prime.$ Multiplying $y = 3z$ by $2$ on both sides and $y = 2z^\prime$ by $3$ on both sides, then subtracting the first equation from the second, gives us $y = 6(z^\prime - z)$. We know $z^\prime - z$ is an integer, and therefore $6$ divides $y. \square$

Answer (score 0):

Proof writing. Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb Z: 6|x\}.$ Let $B=\{x\in Z:2|x\}.$ Let $C=\{x\in Z:3|x\}.$

To prove $$A\subset (B\cap C)\iff$$ $$\iff \forall x\;(x\in A\implies (x\in B\land x\in C)\iff$$ $$\iff \forall x\in \mathbb Z\;(6|x\implies (2|x\land 3|x)).$$ At this point you just present a proof that $2|x$ and $3|x$ whenever $x$ is an integer divisible by $6.$

To prove $(B\cap C)\subset A ,$ : $$(B\cap C)\subset A\iff $$ $$\iff\forall x\;(x\in b\cap C\implies x\in A)\iff$$ $$\iff \forall x\in \mathbb Z\;((2|x\land 3|x)\implies 6|x).$$ At this point you just present  a proof that $6|x$ whenever $x$ is an integer divisible by $2$ and by $3.$

This method of proving equality of sets is often useful, especially in more complicated problems.